# WS dynamic client and complexType parameter

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm trying to create dynamic WS Client and I've got some problems with WS operations with ComplexType parameter. Here is the example:

WebService:

```
@WebMethod
public int testPerson(Person a) {
  return a.getAge();
}



class Person {
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int i) {
        this.age = i;
    };

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

And here is how i invoke WS:

```
Client c = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance().createClient("wsdlPath");
c.invoke("testPerson",...);
```

Ok and my question is what parameter should I pass to invoke this WebService ( as i said the client have to be dynamic so I cant import class Person to client)? Is it possible that I will pass just struct of primitive Types (in this case one element struct with age parameter)? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` if you don't intend to provide it with complex types

Also, you technically don't have to import the `Person` type into the client. All you really need do is be *aware* of the type and use reflection to generate an instance of the class at runtime.

The version of `createClient` you've used here is only good for webservice operations that accept simple types. To be able to pass a complex type to a dynamic webservice client,

1. `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` needs to dynamically generate the necessary support classes with the following:

   ```
   ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
   JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
   Client client = dcf.createClient("wsdlPath", classLoader);
   ```

   This creates the `Client` object and also the necessary pojos.
2. Then you'll be able to call the service with:

   ```
   //Dynamically load an instance of the Person class. You're not importing and you can simply configure the class name as an application property
   Object person = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("foo.bar.Person").newInstance(); 
   Method theMethod = person.getClass().getMethod("setAge", Integer.class);
   theMethod.invoke(person, 55); //set a property

   client.invoke("testPerson", person); //invoke the operation.
   ```

Barring the approach above, the only other alternative is to construct the SOAP payload manually using the [`Dispatch API`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-dispatch-api.html). This is a painstaking approach (be sure it's what you want).

Ultimately, both approaches require you to have some foreknowledge of the types you'll be dealing with during the webservice invocation

Comment: Thank You. Just to expand your question for somebody with same problem : I've used Beanutils lib to add parameters to object, so you dont need to invoke  setters

Comment: How is above code dynamic when you are hardcoding "foo.bar.Person"?

Comment: @Stackee007 - it's dynamic because we're neither hardcoding the WSDL stubs (or endpoint address) nor the actual class type i.e., we're not doing this: `Person person = new Person()`. A basic string parameter can easily be substituted with a value loaded from a property file

Comment: @kolossus `Client client = dcf.createClient("wsdlPath", classLoader)` would generate the classes behind the scenes that is dyanmic. But how `..loadClass("foo.bar.Person")..` dynamic? Please explain `A basic string parameter can easily be substituted with a value loaded from a property file`

Comment: @Stackee007 Both snippets are two steps of the same process, not separate solutions - you're not going to have one without the other. In using a `foo.bar.Person`, you could use a variable and load any arbitrary class in there

Comment: Isn't there a way to have a list of generated pojos that are generated during the creation of the client?

Comment: xjc might generate a `jaxb.index` file if you import the schema @TamásG.